# flask socketio sends data to a reactjs component which has not yet been rendered

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, flask-socketio

I have a flask socketio server wherein if the database is updated, it sends a ping to a flask server and it originates and sends the data to be displayed to certain ports and namespaces.

There are several react pages that use socket.io-client to fetch this data through a socket.on event

the problem is that a react page only renders when the page is opened and the socket connection from the client side for a certain namespace is only made from the componentDidMount

if the server sends data but the page is not rendered, will the data be displayed when I open it?

Comment: Are you receiving the data while the component is not rendered? That's really what matters. Your component must have access to this data when it renders, so some part of your client application must be listening for the data and keeping it safe for when the component needs it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.